# Overriding catalog_product_view.xml does not work

Tags: magento2, overrides

I am trying to override `app/code/Mageants/SampleProduct/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` in my theme. I copied it to `app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Mageants_SampleProduct/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`, made some changes, and redeployed and cleared the cache.

This is not working. I also tried with a template file which worked without any problems, only the XML is making trouble. Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to overwrite layout the path must be `app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Mageants_SampleProduct/layout/override/base/catalog_product_view.xml`

Reference: [Override a layout](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html)

Comment: If you want override a layout of a specific theme, for example: ../layout/override/theme/Magento/luma/catalog_product_view.xml

Answer (score -1):

First, check if It may be already overwritten in *app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml* or not.

> IF not overwrite then add your code into *app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml*

> IF overwrite then update your code into the existing *app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml*

Comment: For **overwrite** layout needs to use `override/base`. Please see my answer.

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk Please read the doc proper if you want to override base layouts then you use override/base.

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk And by the way, the vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml file is not in the base folder. Please check and remove the vote-down.  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html#fedg_layout_override_default

Comment: Sorry for downvote, looks like I've misunderstood the your idea of answer. Please make any changes (edit) to answer for allow me to remove downvote. But anyway, in theme `Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` - extends layout, not overwrite!

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk Yes, you can remove downvote and edit your answer.

Comment: "You last voted on this answer 1 hour ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137141/discussion-between-victor-tihonchuk-and-msquare).